# AWS LoadBalancer - inService N/A

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Classic Load Balancer routing to two EC2 instances.  Both instances run a copy of Laravel, and the servers are deployed to via Capistrano.

For some reason, the AWS Load Balancer console shows the status of each box  as "inService" but if I hover over the tooltip, it says "N/A"

The health checks seem to be passing, and I'm able to access the sites via the browser.  However, im quite certain that in the past, the tooltip had show a more semantic message.  Is it possible that my AWS is detecting a separate issue in regards to accessing my code?

Comment: Mine also show `N/A` but I really can't recall what was there before

Comment: Well, seems like it will show the reason if the status is `Out of service`